# How to get the index of the selected column in data grid view in windows forms using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to get the index of the selected column in DataGridView ? (windows forms using c#)

I have a DataGridView  with 30 columns in it.Now the task is,when the user clicks any of the 30 columns header,the selected column index is shown in message box.I want help to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your code in ColumnHeaderMouseClick

```
   private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString());
    }
```